# Java: How to concat a String array from index 0 to -2 in an elegant way?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm extracting some order page files(html) to Java `Order` class, and I came to this code below:

```
List<Order> orders = Files.walk(Paths.get(path, "orders", "html"))
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .map(this::readFileToString)
        .map(content -> {
            Order order = new Order();
            evaluateXPath("//*[@id='page']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/text()", content)
                    .ifPresent(x -> {
                        String[] results = x.split(" ");
                        if (results.length >= 3) {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < results.length - 2; i++) {
                                stringBuilder.append(results[i]);
                            }
                            order.setConsignee(stringBuilder.toString());
                            order.setPhoneNumber(results[results.length - 2]);
                            order.setAddress(results[results.length - 1]);
                        }
                    });
            return order;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());


//a exception free wrapper method for FileUtils.readFileToString
private String readFileToString(File file) {
    try {
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("read " + file + " failed.");
        return "";
    }
}

private Optional<String> evaluateXPath(String xpath, String content) {
    //a mysterious implementation of evaluateXPath
}
```

My question is how to rewrite that part(which I think is very long and verbose) to a more neat implementation?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < results.length - 2; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(results[i]);
}
order.setConsignee(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Any advice is welcome even though it's about the other part of my code.

Comment: This is really just fine. Is `IntStream.range(0, results.length - 1).mapToObj(i -> results[i]).collect(joining(""));` "neater"? Is `String.join("", Arrays.asList(results).subList(0, results.length - 1))`, "neater"?

Comment: But no need to specify `""` in `joining`. [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) should do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Stream.of(results).limit(results.length-2).collect(Collectors.joining())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it around:

```
if (results.length >= 3) {
    Deque<String> resultList = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(results));
    order.setAddress(resultList.removeLast());
    order.setPhoneNumber(resultList.removeLast());
    order.setConsignee(String.join("", resultList));
}
```